# Where is the accepted answer count on a user profile?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, profile-page

When I browse Stack Overflow, when click on a profile of someone, I see a lot of information about that person, but I can't find the *number of accepted answers*.

Where can I find the accepted answers count? So not the total answers, just those that have been marked as accepted.

Comment: When an answer is accepted, it does not mean it is the "best answer". It only means that at some point in the past the OP found it useful. In fact, on popular questions that accumulate answers over time, the best answer is quite often not the accepted one.

Comment: in 80% cases usefull answer i found accepted as the best answer. I just want know how many accepted answers created by some people.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to use search to find out how many *accepted* answers someone has.

If you are looking at a profile, the search box already comes pre-filled with the `user:<userid>` syntax; all you need to do is add `isaccepted:yes` to that.

For example, as of the time of this answer, you have [121 answers that are accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2057388+isaccepted%3Ayes); after adding `isaccepted:yes` the search box contained:

```
user:2057388 isaccepted:yes
```

and the result list tells you how many results matched that search (as well as show you a list of all answers that are marked accepted).