# Show the amount of own answers being accepted in the user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accepted-answer, user-interface

I can see the amount of answers I have written in my user profile, but that doesn't include the amount of answers being accepted. Can this information be included there as well?

This is the current information:

[image: Answer summary]

This is how it could look like:
[image: Answer summary with accepted information]

Comment: feels irrelevant to me, your answer should be a valid answer to the question regardless of whether the op agrees it is the best answer or not

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275418/6296561

Comment: @JoeTaras Its best to not reason from your own perspective, but rather from how the average joe will look at such statistics. Your suggested view makes it appear that question acceptance is something really important while it really isn't, it'll influence how people start to treat unaccepted answers for the worse. I wouldn't mind having such information displayed somewhere, but then not so prominently front-and-center, put it away somewhere else.

Comment: @Gimby: Your POV is interesting about the side effects of this info. But I've also specified, for me is a completion not an important information. It can be put in another place (like profile tab).

Comment: You won't get this from the devs.   No matter, use SEDE.  A sample query to get you close [is here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i).